# Help understanding the wave number in light

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, fourier-transform

For my final optics project I want to implement the beam propagation method using Fourier transforms. I came across the following document http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcleod/pdfs/NMIP/lecturenotes/NMiP%20BPM.pdf

Most of it makes sense to me.  I am just kind of unsure how to calculate kx ky and kz in the equation or really what they mean.  I looked up that k = 2_pi / lambda in one dimension but I am not sure about 3D.  Can someone please explain?[image]

Comment: in 3d, k is a vector that points in the direction of propagation.  kx, ky, kz are just the cartesian components.  Since k is like (normalized) momentum, its analogous to the velocity vector of, say a particle.  Find kx, ky, kz by dotting into the cartesian coordinates... does this help?

Comment: I guess I am just confused about the idea of direction.  In this example I suppose since I am stepping in the Z direction would k_z = 2_pi / lambda and k_x = k_y = 0?

Comment: Nevermind that.  It just occurred to me that the Fourier transform changes x into k_x, etc.  So I would not need to calculate k_x or k_y because those are just variables used to calculate the inverse transform.  But how do I calculate k_z?

Comment: I guess since I know the norm(k_x, k_y, k_z) = 2 * pi * omega I can just solve for k_z that way.

Comment: yes; transform E(x,y,z,t=0) in the transverse direction to get the initial condition, but in general E will now be specified as a function of the kx, ky variables (and z, t of course).  I'd suggest trying an easy (gaussian) example first, this may clear up your questions.

Comment: I think I got it now.  Just didn't realize the k variables were coming out of the transform.

Answer (score 1):

The term *k, wavenumber,* is another manifestation of *p, momentum*.
The term *Omega, frequency,* is another manifestation of *E, energy*.

As you can see, *frequency* goes with *time* while *wavenumber* goes with *spatial extent*. This mutual game is a by-product of electromagnetism in physics.

Your can see that also by dimensional analysis where both products, *frequency times time,* and *wavenumber times distance* are dimensionless. 
That's why in the big picture of relativistic quantum mechanics (*Quantum Field Theory,*) the *phase*, e.g. (frequency * time - wavenumber * distance) is an *invariant*.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to calculate these values for each step in the beam proporgation